# How to properly link object files written in Haskell?

Tags: c++, haskell, linker, ghc, ffi

Roughly following [this tutorial](https://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2017/01/14/calling-haskell-from-c/), I managed to get this toy project working. It calls a Haskell function from a C++ program.

- `Foo.hs`

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

  module Foo where

  foreign export ccall foo :: Int -> Int -> IO Int

  foo :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
  foo n m = return . sum $ f n ++ f m

  f :: Int -> [Int]
  f 0 = []
  f n = n : f (n-1)
  ```
- `bar.c++`

  ```
  #include "HsFFI.h"
  #include FOO       // Haskell module (path defined in build script)

  #include <iostream>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);

    std::cout << foo(37, 19) << "\n";

    hs_exit();
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- `call-haskell-from-cxx.cabal`

  ```
  name:                call-haskell-from-cxx
  version:             0.1.0.0
  build-type:          Simple
  cabal-version:       >=1.10

  executable foo.so
    main-is:          Foo.hs   
    build-depends:       base >=4.10 && <4.11
    ghc-options:         -shared -fPIC -dynamic
    extra-libraries:     HSrts-ghc8.2.1
    default-language:    Haskell2010
  ```
- build script

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  hs_lib="foo.so"
  hs_obj="dist/build/$hs_lib/$hs_lib"

  ghc_version="8.2.1"                          # May need to be tweaked,
  ghc_libdir="/usr/local/lib/ghc-$ghc_version" # depending on system setup.

  set -x

  cabal build

  g++ -I "$ghc_libdir/include" -D"FOO=\"${hs_obj}-tmp/Foo_stub.h\"" -c bar.c++ -o test.o
  g++ test.o "$hs_obj" \
     -L "$ghc_libdir/rts" "-lHSrts-ghc$ghc_version" \
     -o test

  env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="dist/build/$hs_lib:$ghc_libdir/rts:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" \
    ./test
  ```

This works (Ubuntu 16.04, GCC 5.4.0), printing `893` – but it isn't really robust, namely, if I *remove* the actual invocation of the Haskell function, i.e. the `std::cout << foo(37, 19) << "\n";` line, then it fails at the linking step, with the error message

```
/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libHSrts-ghc8.2.1.so: undefined reference to `base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libHSrts-ghc8.2.1.so: undefined reference to `base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libHSrts-ghc8.2.1.so: undefined reference to `base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libHSrts-ghc8.2.1.so: undefined reference to `base_GHCziWord_W8zh_con_info'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libHSrts-ghc8.2.1.so: undefined reference to `base_GHCziIOziException_cannotCompactPinned_closure'
...
```

Apparently, the inclusion of the Haskell project pulls additional library files in that are needed. How do I explicitly depend on everything necessary, to avoid such brittleness?

---

Output of the build script when the `foo` call is included, with `ldd` on the final executable:

```
++ cabal build
Preprocessing executable 'foo.so' for call-haskell-from-C-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'foo.so' for call-haskell-from-C-0.1.0.0..
Linking a.out ...
Linking dist/build/foo.so/foo.so ...
++ g++ -I /usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/include '-DFOO="dist/build/foo.so/foo.so-tmp/Foo_stub.h"' -c bar.c++ -o test.o
++ g++ test.o dist/build/foo.so/foo.so -L /usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts -lHSrts-ghc8.2.1 -o test
++ env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=dist/build/foo.so:/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts: sh -c 'ldd ./test; ./test'
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff23105000)
    foo.so => dist/build/foo.so/foo.so (0x00007fdfc5360000)
    libHSrts-ghc8.2.1.so => /usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libHSrts-ghc8.2.1.so (0x00007fdfc52f8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdfc4dbe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdfc49f4000)
    libHSbase-4.10.0.0-ghc8.2.1.so => /usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/base-4.10.0.0/libHSbase-4.10.0.0-ghc8.2.1.so (0x00007fdfc4020000)
    libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.1.0-ghc8.2.1.so => /usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/integer-gmp-1.0.1.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.1.0-ghc8.2.1.so (0x00007fdfc528b000)
    libHSghc-prim-0.5.1.0-ghc8.2.1.so => /usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/ghc-prim-0.5.1.0/libHSghc-prim-0.5.1.0-ghc8.2.1.so (0x00007fdfc3b80000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fdfc3900000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fdfc36f3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdfc33ea000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fdfc31e2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdfc2fde000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdfc2dc1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdfc5140000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdfc2bab000)
```

Comment: You probably need to link to at least `base` , i.e. `-L "$ghc_libdir/base-x.y.z.t" "-lHSrts-base-x.y.z.t$ghc_version"` where `x.y.z.t` is your base version.

Comment: You could also try using `ghc` as the linker and including necessary c++ stuff rather than the other way around.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with ghc-8.2.1 and gcc-7.3.0. Please run `ldd ./test` instead of `./test` as the last step of the build script and post the output.

Comment: @Yuras I added the `ldd` info to the question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout what if you add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` as the first argument when linking the executable? E.g. `g++ -Wl,--no-as-needed test.o "$hs_obj" <...>`

Comment: @Yuras yup, then it links successfully even when `foo` isn't invoked. (And gives the same `ldd` output.) But it seems quite one kludge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `ghc` links executables with `-Wl,--no-as-needed` option, and you should use it too. (You can check how `ghc` links executable e.g. using `cabal build --ghc-options=-v3`.)

You can find more details [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10110). My understanding it the next: `foo.so` requires `libHSbase-4.10.0.0-ghc8.2.1.so` to be loaded at runtime as needed, i.e. when we need symbol from it (check `readelf -a dist/build/foo.so/foo.so | grep NEEDED`). So if you don't call `foo`, then `base.so` is not loaded. But ghc needs all libraries to be loaded (I don't know why). The `--no-as-needed` option forces all libraries to be loaded.

Note that `--no-as-needed` options is position-dependent, so put it before the shared library.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to do that then. Could you add some explanation for why this would be necessary?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't know all the details, it is better to ask GHC devs. I added basic explanatioin, but don't rely on it, it could be a complite misunderstanding on my side.

Answer (score 3):

This answer explains what happens during the linkage, why the solution with `-Wl,--no-as-needed` works and what should be done instead to have a somewhat more robust approach.

In a nutshell: `-lHSrts-ghcXXX.so` depends on `libHSbaseXXX.so`, `libHSinteger-gmpXXX.so` and `libHSghc-primXXX.so` which must be provided to the linker during the linkage.

The here proposed solution depends on a lot of manual work and is not very scalable. However I don't know enough about `cabal` to tell you how to automatize this,  but I hope you can make the last step.

Or maybe you will be just fine with using the `-Wl,--no-as-needed`-solution, because you know what happens behind the scenes.

---

Let's start by stepping through the linking process for the version without calling `foo`, in a somewhat simplified manner ([here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) is a great article from Eli Bendersky, even if it is about static linkage):

1. The linker maintains a table of symbols and has to find definitions/machine-code for all of them. Let's simplify and assume, that at the beginning it has only symbol `main` in the table and the definition of this symbol is unknown.
2. The definition of symbol `main` is found it the object-file `test.o`. However, the function `main` uses functions `hs_init` and `hs_exit`. Thus we found the definition of `main`, but it doesn't work unless we know the definitions of `hs_init` and `hs_exit`. So now we have to look for their definitions.
3. In the next step the linker looks at `foo.so`, but `foo.so` doesn't define any symbol we are interested in (`foo` is not used!) and the linker just skips `foo.so` and will never look back.
4. The linker looks at `-lHSrts-ghcXXX.so`. There it finds the definitions of `hs_init` and `hs_exit`. Thus, the whole content of the shared library is used, but it needs definitions of such symbols as for example `base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure`. That means the linker starts to look for definitions of these symbols.
5. There are however no more libraries at the command line, thus the linker has nothing to look at and the linkage fails/is not successful, because definitions of some symbols are missing.

What is different for the case where `foo` is used? After the 2. step not only `hs_init` and `hs_exit` are wanted but also `foo`, which is found in `foo.so`. So `foo.so` must be included.

Due to the way the library `foo.so` was build, there is the following information contained:

```
>>> readelf -d dist/build/foo.so/foo.so | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libHSrts-ghc7.10.3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libHSbase-4.8.2.0-HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM-ghc7.10.3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.0-2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS-ghc7.10.3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libHSghc-prim-0.4.0.0-8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3-ghc7.10.3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgmp.so.10]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]

>>> readelf -d dist/build/foo.so/foo.so | grep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [
          /usr/lib/ghc/base_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM:
          /usr/lib/ghc/rts:
          /usr/lib/ghc/ghcpr_8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3:
          /usr/lib/ghc/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS]
```

From this information, the linker knows which shared libraries are needed (`NEEDED`-flag) and where they can be found on your system (`RPATH`). These libraries are found/opened/processed (i.e. marked as needed) and thus all necessary definitions are present.

You can follow the whole process by adding

```
g++ ...
    -Wl,--trace-symbol=base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure \
    -Wl,--verbose \
    -o test
```

to the linkage-step.

The same thing happens if we enforce that the `foo.so` is included into the resulting executable via `-Wl,--no-as-needed` as suggested by @Yuras.

What is the consequence of this analysis?

We should provide the needed libraries on the command line (after `-lHSrts-ghcXXX.so`) and not depend on them being added per chance through other shared-libraries. Obviously, the somewhat cryptic names are only valid for my installation:

```
g++ ...
   -L/usr/lib/ghc/base_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM  -lHSbase-4.8.2.0-HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM-ghc7.10.3 \
   -L/usr/lib/ghc/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS -lHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.0-2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS-ghc7.10.3 \
   -L/usr/lib/ghc/ghcpr_8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3 -lHSghc-prim-0.4.0.0-8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3-ghc7.10.3 \
   ...
   -o test
```

Now it builds, but doesn't load at the run time (after all the right `rpath` is only set in `foo.so` but `foo.so` isn't used). To fix it we could either extend the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or add `-rpath` the link-command-line:

```
g++ ...
   -L...  -lHSbase-...  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/ghc/base_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM  \
   -L... -lHSinteger-gmp-... -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/ghc/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS \
   -L... -lHSghc-prim-...  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/ghc/ghcpr_8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3 \
   ...
   -o test
```

There must be an utility to get the paths and library-names automatically (cabal seems to do it when building `foo.so`), but I don't know how to do because I have no experience with haskell/cabal.